# How to calculate number of degenerate states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, semiconductor-physics

For example if we need to get number of degenerate states for a particle confined in a 3D box that have energy
$$E=41\frac{\pi ^2 \bar{h}^2}{2m_e L^2}$$
I know that
$$E=\frac{n^2 \pi ^2 \bar{h}^2}{2 m_e L^2} $$
and $$n^2=n_x ^2+ n_y ^2 +n_z ^2$$
$$\Rightarrow n_x ^2+ n_y ^2 +n_z ^2=41$$
But how do I get all the different values of $ (n_x, n_y, n_z)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here could be described as a [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). Given $n$ can take any integer value (not including zero), you have the set of squares up to $36$,

$S = \{1,4,9,16,25,36\}$

and you wish to find subsets of three which sum to $41$. Looking at the subset sum problem this can not be solved analytically but algorithms can be employed.

To do this vigorously you need to form a 3D matrix $6 \times 6 \times 6$ by summing together the relevant squares and then read off the indices where $41$ is achieved, a task made easier with a bit easier with a [computer script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572043/given-a-target-sum-and-a-set-of-integers-find-the-closest-subset-of-numbers-tha).

You must also note that any summation where $n_x \neq n_y \neq n_z$ will form a 6-fold permutation, sets with 2 distinct values will form a 2-fold permutation, whereas for $n_x = n_y = n_z$ the solution is unique.